# Delete All Trustees from Directory on NSS Volume

Tags: nss, novell

I am looking for a quick method of removing all trustees from a particular directory structure in a Novell OES2 NSS volume.  I found a similar question on the [Novell Forums](http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/open-enterprise-server/oes-linux/oes-l-storage-backup/375153-how-remove-all-trustees-nss-volume-post1804863.html) but could not find any additional information on the ncp-remove-trustees.sh script referred to in the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't dig that script out, and I'm not in a position anymore to write one for you. If you have the capability, the script may be retrievable via NNTP. However, if you're willing to put in the time, the hooks are there to write such a thing. The trick is in the _admin VFS area. The interface is described here:

http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Virtual_File_Services

Under that share there is a file called "Volume_Trustees.xml" in the volume area in question (typically each NSS pool has its own name, and each volume is under the pool directory). Simply 'cat'ing that file will give you a list of all the assigned trustees on that volume. This will be in XML format ([doc](http://developer.novell.com/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/index.html?page=/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/data/bp8ffe8.html)). If you then take the info in that file and issue RemoveTrustee commands for each of those directories ([doc](http://developer.novell.com/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/index.html?page=/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/data/bp8ffe8.html)) it should remove all of the trustees for you. This is likely what the script was actually doing.

Novell does provide some Perl examples for accessing these VFS structures ([doc](http://developer.novell.com/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/index.html?page=/documentation//vfs/vfs__enu/data/bp8ffe8.html))